# implement refresh token for REST API authentication

Tags: android, rest, api, oauth-2.0, access-token

I am creating REST API and implementing token based auth/auth with username and password. After reading online it seems I can implement a simple version where on authenticating the Client with username/password I can generate an access token (signed JWT) with a short expiry time and send it to the Client.

I read about refresh token - how they are used to renew and get new access token. I am wondering how can I implement the refresh token part because when the device is Android mobile which can be rooted even the refresh token is not safe. So, how do I implement the refresh token part with safety to get a new access token.

One Approach : Store the refresh token and access token on the mobile in simplest way and then on the Server side analyze the usage of API request - I mean detect any weird usage pattern.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of protection do you need. If you want to prevent the users from accessing your APIs directly, basically you can't do this, even without the root access they can use MITM proxies to sniff the traffic and get all needed information.

For the same reasons you can't protect the user from malicious apps, if they have the root access they can practically access everything.

I think you already answered to your question, you should monitor and analyze API usage on the server side to detect abusive requests.

Comment: so is that how people implement in Production Level as well ? How do companies like facebook, whatsapp protect themselves from MITM proxies?

Comment: You could use Certificate and Public Key Pinning: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning